# Variables that can be used as data types.

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there any way in C++ through I can store the data types in the program like (int, char, std::string etc.) in some particular kind of variable and then use that variable instead, in place of the regular data types (for eg: to declare other variables)?

For eg:-

```
T = some-function("int")
now std::vector < T > is equivalent to std::vector <int> ?
```

Comment: To do this at run-time requires [*reflection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) which C++ doesn't have. Once a source file is compiled into a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) most type-information is gone. For doing it at compile-time use *templates*, which any [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be of help.

Comment: Use templates.  If you want a generic type that is not known at compile time, use `std::variant`

Answer (score 4):

You can use templates and `decltype`.
A minimal, working example based on your snippet:

```
#include<vector>

template<typename T>
T some_function() { return {}; }

int main() {
    // t has type int
    auto t = some_function<int>();
    // vec has type std::vector<int> now
    std::vector<decltype(t)> vec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alias types (give them another name) with the `using` keyword:

```
using vi = std:: vector<int>; // I recommend against such short names
// ...
vi some_vector_with_integers;
```

Of course this happens purely at compile time.

Wrapping such declarations in templates allows for compile programming:

```
template<int N>
using X = std::conditional<(N > 42), int, double>:: type;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a statically typed language, which implies that types pretty much do not exist in the runtime. Function return type is completely defined by parameter types (`const char*`) and cannot depend on parameter values (`"int"`).

Computational flow can be influenced by types, e.g. via overload - but not vice versa. As a result, you cannot "compute" a type by calling some function.

Instead you can use templates/`decltype`/`auto` to produce complex and context-dependent types in compile time, or use polymorphic types.

Polymorphic types do indeed have runtime-defined behavior: you can make your `some-function` return an abstract factory, and then use that factory to produce your objects - their concrete type would be unknown at compile time. Of course, you would still need to instantiate the `vector` with some static type - usually a pointer to the generic class (`AbstractType*`).

The fact that you mention `int`, `char` and `std::string` hints that you probably don't want the whole polymorphic hierarchy and can manage with static types.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) are some templates to determine the result type of calling a function. Notice that the function is not even called - again, the return type only depends on parameter types, not some computation.